# Selecting word in sqlite line

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

How is it possible to read a row in SQLite database like this one:

```
Cars were (green/gray*/red)
```

Result in iOS application:

```
Cars were green
          gray
          red
```

And if you select the right word that sentence will be skipped and in its place there'll be the next one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the right word" and what will be skipped? You are very uncleary about what you have and what you want. Please show some code.

Comment: At first i make iphone application. The right word is correct word, mark with * in row database. All code which i have is not about what i need here..

Comment: I see. That only leaves the "what will be skipped?", "explain more closely what you have", "explain more closely what you want" and "show some of your code" parts of my previos comment. And there's a new question: Why do you mark the correct answer with a star in a VARCHAR field instead of through a normalized database model?

Comment: So i try to make test application (for testing people) where ll be one sentence on screen and people ll be choosing correct word on it. When they make one, they ll do next, then next.. And about ur second part qustion, its for easier adding new sentence in database..